# Plot the Average Value of a Variable using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, median

I have two columns that I would like to plot in a bar chart: "Property_type" and "Price". 
Using the code below, I will plot the "total price" instead of the "median price" for each property type. 
Could you help me fix the code?

```
theme_set(theme_bw())

# Draw plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=Property_type, y=Price)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, fill="tomato3") + 
  labs(title="Ordered Bar Chart", 
       subtitle="Average Price by each Property Type", 
       caption="Image: 5") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

[image: Image Here]

Comment: Simply aggregate before plotting: `ggplot(aggregate(Price ~ Property_type, data, FUN=median), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can calculate the median price for each property and then pass this new variable as y value in `ggplot2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  group_by(Property) %>% 
  summarise(MedPrice = median(Price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Property,-MedPrice), y = MedPrice)) +
  geom_col(fill = "tomato3", width = 0.5)+
  labs(title="Ordered Bar Chart", 
       subtitle="Average Price by each Property Type", 
       caption="Image: 5") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset by following this guide: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one quick question: I know have the median price, but the bars are not ordered from the bars with the highest median price to do the lowest. Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: You're welcome ;) I edited my answer to reorder bars according their median price on the plotting. Let me know if it is ok. If not, please provide a reproducible example in your question

Answer (score 1):

While dc37's answer will get you what you want perfectly, I just wanted to point out that you could also use the `stat_*` family of functions within ggplot to calculate groupwise summary statistics.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Property = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 10),
  Price = rnorm(100, rep(1:10, each = 10))
)

ggplot(df, aes(Property, Price)) +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "col")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Good point ;) For some reasons, I can't remember to use `stat_summary` for this kind of issues.

Comment: I also recently started adopting more of the stat family, can be very convenient.